# ¿Cómo hacer dinámico el atributo src de una imagen con EJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, ejs

la especificación de mi problema es la siguiente: Estoy desarrollando una tienda virtual y los documentos de cada producto se encuentran almacenados en Mongo. Con el texto y demás no hay problema debido a que se invocan como contenido de las mismas etiquetas HTML; sin embargo, al momento de hacer lo mismo con las URL de las imágenes, estas no se llegan a renderizar en el HTML final. Supongo que es porque la invocación de la clave se realiza dentro del atributo en lugar de que sea contenido de la misma etiqueta como es lo habitual.
Les adjunto el fragmento de código con el que estoy teniendo ese inconveniente, aún me estoy iniciando en este mundo por lo que particularidades como esta se me dificultan un poco, gracias de antemano :)

```
            <div class="productsPanel">
            <% if (arrayProductsDB.length > 0) { %> 
                <% arrayProductsDB.forEach(product => { %> 
                <div class="productGrid">
                    <div class="productImgCont">
                        <img class="productThumbnail" src=" <%= product.imgURL %>  " alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class="productName">
                        <%= product.nombre %> 
                    </p>
                    <p class="productPrize">S/.<%= product.precio %> </p>
                    <ul class="productSpecs">
                        <li class="productSpec"><%= product.marca %> </li>
                        <li class="productSpec"><%= product.caracteristicas.color %> </li>
                        <li class="productSpec"><%= product.caracteristicas.almacenamiento %> </li>
                        <li class="productSpec"><%= product.caracteristicas.procesador %> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btnBuy"><a href="/menu/producto">COMPRAR</a></button>
                </div>
                <% }) %> 
            <% } %>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar cómo tienes configurado tu servidor de Express?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si en realidad estuve revisando bien el código y había pasado por alto el colocar la clave imgURL en el schema de Mongoose, es por ello que no se renderizaba correctamente pero ya lo pude solucionar, muchas gracias de todas formas.